# Trying to Create one figure with 5 subplots that are an iteration of one variable changing in steps of 1 - Why is it not working?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, iteration, subplot, figure

```
clear all; close all; clc;

%% parameters

rho = 1;
k0 = 1;
K = 1;
y1 = 0.1;
for gamma = 1:5;
mu = 0.06;
mu0 = 0.06;
sigma0 = 0.15;
sigmae = 0.1;
sigmaS = 0.1;
beta = 1-(1-0.04)/252;
sigmaS = linspace(0.05,0.5,100);
precision_S = 1./sigmaS.^2;


mbar_plus = mu0+0.01; % assuming sentiment increases 0.5% after announcement
mbar_minus = mu0;
sigmahat_plus = sqrt(1./(1/sigma0^2+1/sigmae^2+1./sigmaS.^2));
sigmahat_minus = sqrt(1/(1/sigma0^2+1/sigmae^2));
varm_minus = (1/sigmae^2)./(1/sigma0^2+1/sigmae^2)^2;
varm_plus =  (1/sigmae^2)./(1/sigma0^2+1/sigmae^2+1./sigmaS.^2).^2;

%%%%%%% solution assuming UNSCHEDULED announcement
%% announcement premium vs. sigmaS
%% premium 1 is the pure disagreement term 
%% premium 2 is the interaction term of disagreement and sentiment, assuming sentiment = true
p_plus = beta*(mbar_plus - gamma*sigmahat_plus.^2*K).*exp(-varm_plus./(2.*sigmahat_plus.^2)-(mbar_plus - y1).*gamma.*K + gamma.*sigmahat_plus.^2.*K^2./2);
R_plus= (mbar_plus - gamma.*sigmahat_plus.^2*K)./p_plus;
p_minus = beta*(mbar_minus - gamma*sigmahat_minus.^2*K).*exp(-varm_minus./(2.*sigmahat_minus.^2)-(mbar_minus - y1).*gamma.*K + gamma.*sigmahat_minus.^2.*K^2./2);
premium_1 = (mbar_plus - gamma.*sigmahat_plus.^2.*K)./(mbar_plus - gamma.*sigmahat_minus.^2.*K);
premium_2 = (mbar_plus-gamma.*sigmahat_minus.^2*K)./(mbar_minus-gamma.*sigmahat_minus.^2*K).*exp(-(mbar_plus-mbar_minus).*gamma*K);
premium = premium_1.*premium_2;

%% plot

    figure;
    hold on
    for i = 1:5
            subplot(1,5,i);
            plot(precision_S,premium{i},'Linewidth',2);
            title(['Announcement premium - Gamma=' , num2str(gamma)])
            xlabel('1/\sigma_S^2')
            ylabel('p^+/p^-')
    end
end
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

When I try and index with i, it returns "Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type. I'm simply trying to create one figure with 5 different subplots that are an iteration of one changing variable in an
equation.

Comment: You should of course mention the language of the question in the tags. But the problem has nothing to do with the plotting, but rather you can't index brace index into whatever `premium`  is. But you unfortunately chose to omit what it even is. For all we know `premium` is a string.

Comment: I've edited the question so to show what premium is. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, the error happens before any plotting can occur, so even mentioning plotting is a red herring.

Brace indexing is what MATLAB uses for cell arrays, quite similar to the plain list in python. It can be used to store arbitrary objects. It could be different objects with data for your array

```matlab
premiums = {[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]};
premiums{1}   % our first dataset
```

However, there is nothing in this code that creates any form of cell array, so there should not be any expectation that to index anything with such an array.

Hard to tell from the lack of proper indentation in your code, but your `gamma` loop encompasses almost the entire code, and your `premium` is just a temporary value which is computed for just 1 of the desired plots at the time.

Inside the `gamma` loop, you have a nested loop, again over 5 values. Did you perhaps mean for these to be the same as `gamma`? If so, then your inner loop should be taken out, `i` replaced with `gamma` and `figure; hold on` be placed outside the outer loop.

Alternatively, you could actually end the first loop, storing actual `premium` values into a cell array.

```matlab
premiums = {}
for gamma = 1:5
   ...
   premiums{gamma} = premium
end

figure;
hold on
for gamma = 1:5
    subplot(...);
    plot(precision_S, premiums{gamma})
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So sorry about all the errors in the question, but I appreciate you sifting through them all to give me a very concise solution.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if you feel your question have been answered.